# What is the default time taken while navigating from for view to another view in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I need a small clarification, I've 2 UIViewControllers on pressing on a button from one viewcontroller,I need to navigate to other. But I need to know what is the time taken internally by this UIViewContoller, when we call some this like this.

```
MyViewController *ins = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ins animated:YES];
```

We all know if that "animated" if "YES" then it will take some time , I need that time or help me in calculating that time.

Comment: Why do you need to know? I wouldn't make any assumptions about it. The time could change in an iOS update.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I believe there are cases where the animation can be scheduled *after* the containing function exits.  So, you can't rely on timing it.  Generally, patterns which rely on strict implicit event sequencing are extremely error-prone in iOS.  I advise finding a different way of solving the problem.  You're going to have difficult to trace bugs one way or another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why have this question, but I did a small demo to verify this -

Without animation -

Printed timeframe before push - 05/03/2017 11:07:35.**7480**

Printed timeframe after push - 05/03/2017 11:07:35.**7550**

With animation -

Printed timeframe before push - 05/03/2017 11:09:42.**9680**

Printed timeframe after push - 05/03/2017 11:09:42.**9760**

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let bVC = AHBViewController()
    bVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let startDate = Date()
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: startDate))
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bVC, animated: true)
    let endDate = Date()
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: endDate))

}
```

Comment: Thanks you , I appreciate your timely answer. The task is I need to check whether any possibility for reducing the time taken during the navigation from one controller to other.

Comment: Say for example from your example "9760 - 9680 = 80" milli seconds is the delay or time taken to navigate . I need to check any other possibility of reducing that 80 milliseconds to 70 or 60.

Comment: Ok, got you. I don't suggest to have optimization on this, this is very basic feature in cocoa touch, and I do believe Apple consider the performance of push action very seriously even start at the beginning.

Comment: Yes , This is a small work around for which I'm going to try, anyways thanks for your support.